# object-fit: cover not working when changing flex direction

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my example everything works as it should in wide screen – the image is set to `object-fit: cover`, so when i make the browser window smaller, it crops the edges of the image left and right to fit all content.

However, as soon as I hit @media and change my flex-direction to column, the image gets scaled down (like it would be set to `contain`), not cropped. It should crop top and bottom in this case to fit everything (without scroll bars).

Note that as soon as I remove the image, the flexbox layout itself works as intended. What am I missing?!?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 5vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 5vh;
}

.imagestage {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.textstage {
  flex: 1;
  order: 1; /* put the textstage on the left */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* mobile layout */
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* PREVIEW COLOURS AND STYLING */
.body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
header {
  background-color: rgb(38, 74, 74);
}
.imagestage {
  background-color: rgb(56, 56, 112);
}
.textstage {
  background-color: rgb(96, 34, 34);
}
footer {
  background-color: rgb(91, 65, 32);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <div class="textstage">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, possimus facilis. Porro quis officia.
      </div>
      <div class="imagestage">
        <img class="fit" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1372401945/photo/modern-black-picture-or-square-photo-frame-isolated.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=bmXOZlLuoGDq9RtS64i1JWl8nz1lKg-2hVE1SRT8I8E=" width="auto" height="auto" />
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um… there was a quite helpful answer here (thanks again, stranger!), which somehow… vanished?!? Anyway, while it did not completely fix my specific case, it might be helpful for others running into this problem, so I'll try to recap:

1. One approach was to use background-image instead (so it's in the CSS).
2. The other approach was to add this to the CSS:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .imagestage {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .fit {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

3. What I finally used. Also a workaround, but it comes really close, and works best for my case:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .imagestage {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .imagestage img {
    margin-top: -20%;
    margin-bottom: -20%;
  }
}
```